# How to adjust background of text to length of words with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the background of my text to extend according to the length of the words, but as I have to set the `position` to `absolute` in order to align the text to the bottom of its parent, the background renders as a block [(Like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eoda.png) If I set the `position` to `relative` it doesn't place the text at the bottom of its parent[(Like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG8Kq.png) If this was a unique element in the website, I wouldn't mind adjusting the position with `bottom: XXpx;` but I have more texts with different lengths so I don't want to adjust one by one.

So to summarize, I want the background of the text to behave like in the second example, but in the position of the first example.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.box{
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color:black;
}

.label-absolute{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.label-relative{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span class="label-absolute">read <br>between<br>the lines</span></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="box"><span class="label-relative">read <br>between<br>the lines</span></div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an extra wrapper:

```css
.box {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}

.label-absolute {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.label-absolute>span {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span class="label-absolute"><span>read <br>between<br>the lines</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way around this may be to use nested elements; the parent would be `absolute` to allow your desired positioning, and the child will be `relative`, and will have the `background-color` set:

```css
.box{
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color:black;
}
.label { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
.label > .content {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="content">read <br>between<br>the lines</span>
  </div>
</div>
```